# Pros and cons of having webcomponents per repo

Tags: repository, web-component

We've recently starting to implement web components in our app, the hope is that these web components can be shared to different clients in the future. My primary role is to have this process to be as simple so maintenance won't be too much work. We started of on having one web component per repo it dawn at me that we could potentially have 100s of core repos * (# of clients), making it seem crazy to maintain with lots of overhead. I'm just not sure if a very granular repo structure is the best way to do it. I just don't know how to maintain such setup.

- Option 1: One component per repo
- Option 2: One feature per repo
- Option 3: One repo per client

I need to find the balance of flexibility and the operational maintenance of each option.

Comment: What is a client? What kind of repo?

Comment: client is the organization who will be using our service. Our repo is git-based, Bitbucket.